# Как использовать app.listen, если сайт на хостинге

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, express

Подскажите чем мне заменить 5000 порт, если сайт на хостинге, я так понимаю 5000 актуально только для локального сервера... Заранее извиняюсь, полный ноль в этой части

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425193/does-a-node-js-application-have-to-listen-on-a-port

Answer (score 0):

Создайте переменную `port` присвойте ей значение: `process.env.PORT || 5000`

Детали про `process.env.PORT` за [ссылкой](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/345724/)
Пример:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server Running"));
```

Comment: делаю как вы предлагаете, получаю Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: @ЭминПогосбеков https://qna.habr.com/q/733989